# ¿Porque al darle scroll al spinner se reinicia la posicion?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un spinner que se adapata a un arreglo que tengo en el archivo Strings, el problema es que al momento de darle scroll se regresa y no me deja ver los demas valores.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.categorias, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_custom);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item_custom);
        categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Arreglo que se encuentra en el archivo strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="categorias">
        <item>Comida</item>
        <item>Transporte</item>
        <item>Casa</item>
        <item>Mantenimiento</item>
        <item>Gasolina</item>
        <item>Coche</item>
        <item>Entretenimiento</item>
        <item>Deporte</item>
        <item>Bebé</item>
        <item>Mascota</item>
        <item>Belleza</item>
        <item>Electrónica</item>
        <item>Regalos</item>
        <item>Social</item>
        <item>Viajes</item>
        <item>Educación</item>
        <item>Libros</item>
        <item>Oficina</item>
        <item>Otros</item>
 </string-array>
```

Comment: Como que se regresa ? no entiendo el problema

Comment: Tengo 28 datos en un spinner y cuando abres el spinner solo muestra 6(1,2,3,4,5,6) y entonces deslizas hacia arriba para ver los restantes(7,8,9,10,11,12) y vuelves a deslizar hacia arriba y se regresa a los primeros 1,2,3,4,5,6 y no te deja ver los demás

Comment: @Adrian revisa el uso de setSelection() eso debe ser una causa y comenta.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el código que muestras no tiene problema alguno, pero posiblemente estes usando en algún punto de tu código el método `setSelection()`, esto provocaría que regresara a los primeros elementos.

```
spinner.setSelection(...);
```